# Using Terraform, how can I pass in a list of users from module to module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to use Terraform's public modules and I created a lot of IAM users like so:

```
module "iam_finance_users" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-user"
  version = "5.9.1"

  for_each = var.finance_users
  name          = each.value
  force_destroy = true
  create_iam_access_key = false
  password_reset_required = true
}
```

My *variables.tf* file has the following:

```
variable "finance_users" {
  type = set(string)
  default = ["mary.johnson@domain.com","mike.smith@domain.com"....]
}
```

Now I am trying to add these users to a group like so

```
module "iam_group_finance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-group-with-policies"
  version = "5.9.1"

  name = "finance"
  group_users = ["${module.iam_finance_users.iam_user_name}"]

  attach_iam_self_management_policy = true
  custom_group_policy_arns = [
    "${module.iam_read_write_policy.arn}",
  ]
}
```

But no matter what I try I still keep getting errors. I have a list of users in a variable and I want to add all those users created in that module to the group module. I know I'm close but I can't quite seem to close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you used `for_each` in the module, you have to use `values` to access elements of all instances of the module created:

```
group_users = values(module.iam_finance_users)[*].iam_user_name
```

Comment: This worked! thank you so much! Now another question for anyone here actually is how can use the same password for all users?  Since it's forcing every user to change it I don't see why I can't make one password for 30 IAM Users I need to create.

Answer (score 1):

It's often helpful to know what the error is. In versions of Terraform v1.0 or newer, the errors become fairly explanatory. The error you were likely getting was something similar to:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 14, in output "iam_finance_users":
│   14:   value = module.iam_finance_users.iam_user_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.iam_finance_users is object with 2 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "iam_user_name".
```

The solutions, which both work, can be tested using the following example code:

Module 1: `modules/iam-user`

```
variable "name" {
  type = string
}

output "iam_user_name" {
  value = "IAM-${var.name}"
}
```

Module 2: `modules/iam-group-with-policies`

```
variable "group_users" {
  type = set(string)
}

output "iam-users" {
  value = var.group_users
}
```

Root module (your code):

```
variable "finance_users" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = ["mary.johnson@domain.com", "mike.smith@domain.com"]
}

module "iam_finance_users" {
  source = "../modules/iam-user"

  for_each = var.finance_users
  name     = each.value
}

module "iam_group_finance" {
  source = "../modules/iam-group-with-policies"

  # This works...
  group_users = values(module.iam_finance_users)[*].iam_user_name

  # This also works...
  group_users = [for o in module.iam_finance_users : o.iam_user_name]
}

output "group_users" {
  value = module.iam_group_finance.iam-users
}
```

You can easily test each module along the way using `terraform console`.

E.g.:

```
terraform console

> module.iam_finance_users
{
  "mary.johnson@domain.com" = {
    "iam_user_name" = "IAM-mary.johnson@domain.com"
  }
  "mike.smith@domain.com" = {
    "iam_user_name" = "IAM-mike.smith@domain.com"
  }
}
```

Here you can see why it didn't work. The module doesn't spit out a list in that way, so you have to iterate through the module to get your variable. This is why both the `for` method as well as the `values` method works.

Look at how differently a single module is handled:

```
module "iam_finance_users" {
  source = "../modules/iam-user"

  name = tolist(var.finance_users)[1]
}
```

```
terraform console

> module.iam_finance_users
{
  "iam_user_name" = "IAM-mike.smith@domain.com"
}
```

Notice that when not inside a loop (`foreach`), that the single `iam_user_name` is accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I went with the values() function but this really helps me understand a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:
This is untested, so you might need to tweak a bit. Reference thread: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/for-each-objects-to-list/36609/2

```
module "iam_group_finance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-group-with-policies"
  version = "5.9.1"
  name = "finance"
  group_users =  [  for o in module.iam_finance_users : o.iam_user_name ]
  attach_iam_self_management_policy = true
  custom_group_policy_arns = [
    module.iam_read_write_policy.arn
  ]
}
```